# Accessing assets from public folder,inside a view(Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, phpmailer

I cannot access assets in my view.

Here is my code.

```
 $mail->addAttachment(asset($file), 'receiptFile', 'base64', 'application/octet-stream');
```

The browser shows the following error:

> Could not access file:
>   http://localhost/receiptGenerator2/public/5a46187d954de.png Message
>   could not be sent.Mailer Error: Could not access file:
>   http://localhost/receiptGenerator2/public/5a46187d954de.png ------

As you can see the path to the file was successfully located.

If Laravel can find the file,why is it showing the error.

Comment: you can pass anything to `asset` and it will generate a URL regardless of whether that is valid or it exists, its not 'finding' anything

Comment: what version of Laravel?

Comment: is receiptGenerator2/public/5a46187d954de.png located on the disk or being generated somehow ?

Comment: Version is 5.5.28

Comment: No the path is absolutely correct.When i put the path on the browser, the browser opens the png image.

Comment: The png file is in my public folder

Comment: where do you see them using a URL and not a file path in their docs or examples?

Answer (score 1):

Please try that way 
Use asset and give image name and if file is any folder than give {{ **asset('folder_name/image_name') }}**

```
{{ asset('5a46187d954de.png') }}
```

Its generate  http://localhost/receiptGenerator2/public/5a46187d954de.png

Comment: the {{ }} are to use php commands such as asset in a blade view. Since he is in the controller those are not required.  Check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers

Comment: that's exactly what I'm doing.I'm getting the right path.

Comment: No I'm in the view.

Comment: I'm using <?php  ?>,so {{}} is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
->attach(
   public_path('receiptGenerator2/public/5a46187d954de.png'), [
   'as' =>"attachment.png" ,
   'mime' => 'application/octet-stream',
]);
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#attachments

Edit: Since you're using phpmail this should do the trick

```
 $mail->addAttachment(public_path($file), 'receiptFile', 'base64','application/octet-stream');
```

Mail requires the full path, yes you can open the file from that url from the browser but the phpmailer attempts to access  http://localhost/receiptGenerator2/public/5a46187d954de.png in your disk, so it tries to get the file from /var/www/html/project/ http://localhost/receiptGenerator2/public/5a46187d954de.png which is not valid.

Comment: Bro I'm in the view.It throws an error.attach is an unknown method.

Comment: Well my bad, it is not normal to attempt to send emails in views so i assumed you were in a controller.

Comment: Are you using laravel mail facade or PHPmail ?

Comment: I'm using PHP Mailer

Comment: Bro You're a champion.I love you.I spent 3 hours on this.Thank you.

Comment: Still recomend you to check out the documentation i sent of laravel. Following MVC patterns accordingly may save you alot of time in the future. Since your problem is solved dont forget to accept answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As [the docs for `addAttachment()`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addAttachment) say, the first parameter must be a local file system path; it will not work if you give it a URL. PHPMailer isn't an HTTP client - there are many other functions and libraries to help with that, so use them if you need to fetch something from a remote URL to use as an attachment. You should not be using localhost URLs for local resources anyway as it's unnecessarily inefficient.